# is it possible install jdk from local using sdkman

Tags: java

Now I am using sdkman to install jdk from internet failed, because of the network access problem, I could not install jdk. Now I want to using sdkman instal sdk from local. I think the procedure would like this:

1. download jdk tar.gz file from internet
2. copy the file to some folder
3. using sdkman to install jdk from local path

is it possible? I have already download jdk like this:

```
wget -c https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/AdoptOpenJDK/11/jdk/x64/linux/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the JAVA JDK files will be extracted to `candidates/java` directory.

- You can extract the required jdk directory into

  ```
  ${SDKMAN_DIR}/candidates/java/.
  ```
- In linux it will be in general `.sdkman` in `/home/<user>`

  ```
  /home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java
  ```
- It will be shown as unclassified.

  ```
  sdk list java

  ===== Available Java Versions=================

  Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
  ------------------------------------------------- 

  Unclassified  | >>> | dcevm        | none    | local only | dcevm-11.0.11_1
  ```

Use the following command to install it permanently:

```
sdk default java dcevm-11.0.11_1
```

Then set the `JAVA_HOME` path if required.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use your own directory you can run this command

```
sdk install java 1.9 /home/xxx/java/jdk/jdk-9.0.4
```

Then on the list will look as unclassified

```
sdk list java

               |     | 6.0.119      | zulu    | installed  | 6.0.119-zulu        
 Unclassified  | >>> | 1.9          | none    | local only | 1.9                 
=====================================================================
```

Then use it

```
sdk use java 1.9
```